# How do I change number to word in linux?

Tags: linux, sed

How can I change every 1 character to the word "one".

I want to change only if it's alone, for example, `11` has to remain like this.

The following command won't find it on the beginning or on the end of the line:

```
sed -Ei 's/([^0-9])0([^0-9])/\nulla\2/g' $1
```

Comment: `\n` does not have a meaning..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The following command won't find it on the beginning or on the end of the line:

So match beginning and ending too.

```
sed -E 's/([^0-9]|^)1([^0-9]|$)/\1one\2/g'
```

But it's simpler to use [gnu extension `\b`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#regexp-extensions):

```
sed 's/\b1\b/one/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\<1\>/one/g' file
```

The `\<` and `\>` are start and end of word zero character place holders.